# Mysql where clause in comparison with integer to column type char

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this table structure

| Name | Type | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | char | 36 |
| name | varchar | 255 |
| description | text |  |

When I run this query below, it return records. I am expecting zero.

```
select * from template where uuid = 9 order by id desc;
```

[image]

Can someone explain please?

Comment: ...and if you put `where uuid='9'`? The `uuid` column contains strings that happen to begin with a number

Comment: What are you leaving out of your question, because that query is not going to return rows from that table.   You tagged this as a laravel question, why?

Comment: See duplicates; and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html